# Go Release Binaries failed

Tags: go, github-actions

I'm trying to build my go project with github action and releasing it on my own repository. As mentioned [Go Release Binaries](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/go-release-binaries), I wrote my own .yml file but I got error on building flow.

```yaml
name: Release API binary

on:
  push:
    tags:
      - "*"

jobs:
  build:
    name: GO API build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        goos: [linux]
        goarch: [amd64, arm64]

    steps:
      - name: Check out code into the Go module directory
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Setup go and release
        uses: wangyoucao577/go-release-action@v1.34
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN  }}
          goos: ${{ matrix.goos }}
          goarch: ${{ matrix.goarch }}
          project_path: "./api"
          binary_name: "flying-server"
```

The project directory is like this:

-> Project root
--> api
---> main.go
---> go.mod
---> go.sum

My error on github action is just like this

[image: Error Code]

Additional Note:
I tried to create a tag version with

> git tag v0.0.13

then pushed it

> git push origin v0.0.13

Based on the procedure above, I want to build a Go project and release it on the repository. I searched for this error, but I could not understand where the problem was.

Comment: Are you sure the tag is there? Can you see it in https://github.com/YOURNAME/YOURREPO/tags? By default, `git push` doesn't push tags. Try `git push --tags` if you can see that the remote doesn't have the tags.

Comment: Yes, I tried to push them with tags and got the same error.

Comment: Do you see the tag in GitHub?

Comment: Yes, I can see the pushed tag. (v0.0.13)

Comment: Please post the text of the error, not a screencap

Comment: Lines 247 to 249 are my problem which cannot permit me to build a successful binary.